# Selecting Date Range from Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, datetime, datatable

I have a dataset in R which I read in using read.table (Table Name a) . I want to select dates from '2007-02-01' to '2007-02-02'. The Current Date Column is of class "Character".

```
     Date     
1 16/12/2006               
2 16/12/2006            
3 16/12/2006             
4 16/12/2006            
5 16/12/2006              
6 16/12/2006
```

I tried the following:
1. as.Date(a$Date) returns date in the format "0016-12-20"
2. a[a$Date >= '2007-02-01' & a$Date <= '2007-02-01'] returns all rows with 0 variables
3. strptime(a$Date,'%d%b%Y') returns NA values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert date to date class and subset :

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
subset(df, Date >= as.Date('2007-02-01') & Date <= as.Date('2007-02-02'))
```

You can also use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date('2007-02-01') & Date <= as.Date('2007-02-02'))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! A couple of questions:  
1. Don't we use %b for month?  
2. Will as.POSIXlt work on the Date column?

Comment: `%b` is used when you have months like "Jan", "Feb" etc. 2) Posixlt can work on dates but it is used mostly with date and time here we only have dates.